# How does for loop work in Ada when you want to loop from a specific year to another?

Tags: ada

I really do not understand the for loop in Ada programming even though I can use it in c++. For example in Ada you should write `for I in 0..7 loop` but if you write `for I in 0..year loop`, then you get a compiler error which says `year` is incompatible. So how should I use for loop in Ada if I want to loop from a specific year to another specific year? Lets say i want my code to look like this. However this will not compile.

```
  with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
  with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
  with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

 procedure Population is
  Min, Max: Integer;
  type percent is range Min..Max;
begin
for I in percent'Range loop
    Put_Line("I is "& percent'Image(I));
 end loop;
 end Population;
```

Comment: You haven't shown us how `year` is declared. Please include a [mre] in your question.

Comment: Please also include the exact text of the compiler error message.

Comment: At the time of declaration of type Percent values of Min and Max are not defined, and as such neither is the range of Percent.

Comment: Thank you for including an example in your question -- but this is not the same problem you originally asked about. There's a compile-time error on the declaration of `percent`: "non-static expression used for integer type bound", before you even get to the `for` loop. In the code you originally asked about, how was `year` declared?

Answer (score 5):

Answering the original incomplete question; ignoring the later completely unrelated example. Both ends of the range have to be the same type. Then the loop variable will automatically be of that type.

Your error message suggests `year` is of a new type, not `Integer` such as

```
type years is new integer range 0 .. 2020;
year : years := 1999;  -- party like its 1999
```

If the literal 0 is in the range of your year type, this will still work, because integer literals are of a hypothetical type "Universal Integer" compatible with all integer types. If it's outside the range, you'll get a Constraint Error exception at runtime, and the Gnat compiler will issue a warning about this during compilation.

If another integer variable V is in the range of your year type, you can make V into a year by a type conversion `years(V)`.

Again there are runtime consequences if V is out of range; however the compiler cannot warn in advance unless the range of V's type does not overlap with the range of years.

Of course, `for i in year1 .. year2` is just fine where `year1` and `year2` are both of type `years`.

But if you'll be mixing integers and years a lot, make year a subtype of integer not a new type. Less safe but more convenient. It will catch out of range values, but won't complain if you mix integers and years...

```
subtype years is integer range 0 .. 2020;
```

Any discrete type can be used as a loop variable, and/or to index an array : that includes enumerations so

```
for i in Boolean'range loop
   put_line(Boolean'image(i));
end loop;
```

should print
FALSE
TRUE

Now here's a useful thing to know : whenever you declare an array, you have also declared a unique type (strictly, a subtype) which indexes that array. That can be used as a loop variable...

```
for i in my_array'range loop
   do_something_with(my_array(i));
end loop;
```

which CANNOT index outside the array...

Comment: Given your declarations `type years is new integer range 0 .. 2020;` `year : years := 1999;` this loop: `for i in 0 .. year loop null; end loop;` is valid. The literal `0` isn't of type `Integer`, it's of type *universal-integer*. The loop is valid as long as `year` is of *some* integer type. We don't know how `year` is declared. I've asked the OP to include a [mre] in the question.

Comment: But that wouldn't cause the compile-time error the OP reported. (I get "incompatible types in range" if `year` is of a floating-point type, but I don't want to speculate about the code the OP hasn't yet shown us.)

Comment: A type conversion is never needed with numeric literals. Integer literals are implicitly converted to any integer type, and real literals to any real type.

Comment: I suggest that, rather than updating your answer with a correction, you just delete the incorrect part and make the answer correct. The error has only been there for a day or so; the answer itself could be there for years, and future readers don't need to see extraneous information.

Comment: Note that `for I in Boolean'range loop` is the same as `for I in Boolean loop`.